# php form submit and thank you message with their name

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I am new so apologise for making a mess of my previous question. But, thank fully I have already figured half the solution.

I am currently using a simple html form:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="eMail Address">
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="message">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Then I am submitting this data into mysql, and sending thank you mail.

```
<?php 
        include_once 'dbconnect.php';
        $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
        $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $_POST['last']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $_POST['email']);
        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, 
        user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email','$message');";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $to      = 'myemail@email.com';
        $subject = "New Message From Your Website";
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['first'] . ' <myemail@email.com>' . 
        "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: myemail@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        header("location:../thankyou.html);
?>
```

Now, my issue is on thank you page, I'd like to greet the user who filled form by saying 
'Hello 'name', thank you for filling the form. Would you like to make a donation?'
But, I can't seem to understand if multiple users sign up how do I send this thank you to the right person each time?

I have just updated this question, apologise if I made any mistakes. I am very new on this forum.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have written so far?

Comment: @Kaz Please insert your code into your question rather than commenting each piece. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sure, I did think it looked untidy. I'll do so. In fact let me ask the question again. as i have already discovered half the solution.

Comment: I have updated the question, can you guys please help and point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Store the name in a session, use `thankyou.php` as redirect and read the session name from there, display it, remove it.

Comment: Thank you, I am now learning how sessions work. If you have any practical tutorials please do share. Or otherwise, still, thank you v much for good pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `<?= $_POST['name']; />` or `<?= $_GET['name']; />` into the email body where the name should be?

How is the body of the email generated?

Comment: yes sir, as I asked this question I discovered the solution for the email. it is working with $_POST['name']. My second part is to say thank you 'name' on my thank you redirect page and suggest them to make a donation. How do I do that?

Comment: please check my edited question again and point me in the right direction if possible. thank you

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE

```
header("location:../thankyou.html);
```

TO

```
header("location:../thankyou.php?fname=".$_POST['first']."&lname=".$_POST['first'].");
```

and use `$_GET['first']` & `$_GET['last']` where you want the name

OR

```
header("location:../thankyou.php?id=5
```

Where "5" is the insert id in your mysql database. You will query for the 'id' to get the name and insert it in the texte.

Comment: I tried first suggestion, it gave syntax error, so I reduced the suggestion to ['first'] and it worked. But, on my thankyou.php when I try and fetch the value it does not show up with echo. I am using this on my thankyou.php .. `echo $_GET['first']`. I do see it in my url but not when I am using it with echo.

Comment: Also, I would like to learn your second method, can you either elaborate on that or point me to some cookbook where I can learn this method. If this works better and is more secure compared to first option. finally thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Had an error, should have been $_GET['fname'] and $_GET['lname'].

Comment: Great, that worked. Can you check if there is an error if I wan't to get both 'fname' and 'lname' as I am getting syntax order as soon I go past ?fname=".$_POST['first']

Comment: ` ?fname=".$_POST['first'] `

should be like

` ?fname=".$_POST['first']."&".$_POST['lasy']." `

the second method you would use ` $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); `